How to delete a git branch locally and remotely in version-control?
In the manual pages about version control I find the instructions on how to create and switch to branches, also for Git repositories. But I can't find information on how to delete a branch – both locally and remotely – in a Git repository.
Which commands should I use? or is it not possible with Emacs' built-in version-control?

Not a definitive answer but I did want to point you to a statement in the doc: VC’s support for branch operations is currently fairly limited. For decentralized version control systems, it provides commands for updating one branch with the contents of another, and for merging the changes made to two different branches (see Merging Branches)... . You may have to do these things from the command line.

Thank you @NickD ! Please feel free to post that as an answer.

I don't know for sure that you cannot delete a branch from VC, so I hesitate to make it an answer: it's more of a hint at this point.
